# Handle 420 response code returned by Tweepy api

Tags: python, twitter, error-handling, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

Whenever a user logs in to my application and searches I have to start a streaming API for fetching data required by him.

***Here is my stream API class***

```
import tweepy
import json
import sys

class TweetListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_connect(self):
        # Called initially to connect to the Streaming API
        print("You are now connected to the streaming API.")

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        # On error - if an error occurs, display the error / status code
        print('An Error has occured: ' + repr(status_code))
        return False

    def on_data(self, data):
        json_data = json.loads(data)
        print(json_data)
```

***Here is my python code file which calls class above to start Twitter Streaming***

```
import tweepy
from APIs.StreamKafkaApi1 import TweetListener
consumer_key = "***********"
consumer_secret = "*********"
access_token  = "***********"
access_secret = "********"
hashtags = ["#ipl"]

def callStream():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

    tweetListener = TweetListener(userid,projectid)
    streamer = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweetListener)
    streamer.filter(track=hashtags, async=True)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    callStream()
```

But if I hit more than twice my application ***return error code 420***. 
I thought to ***change API(using multiple keys)*** used to fetch data whenever Error 420 occurs.

How to get error raised by the ***on_error*** method of ***TweetListener*** class in ***def callStream()***

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add onto @Andy Piper's answer. Response 420 means your script is making too many requests and has been Rate Limited. To resolve this, here is what I do(in class TweetListener):

```
def on_limit(self,status):
    print ("Rate Limit Exceeded, Sleep for 15 Mins")
    time.sleep(15 * 60)
    return True
```

Do this and the error will be handled.

If you persist on using multiple keys. I am not sure but try exception handling on TweetListener and streamer, for tweepy.error.RateLimitError and use recursive call of the function using next API key?

```
def callStream(key):
    #authenticate the API keys here
    try:
        tweetListener = TweetListener(userid,projectid)
        streamer = tweepy.Stream(api.auth, tweetListener)
        streamer.filter(track=hashtags, async=True)
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        if e.reason[0]['code'] == "420":
            callStream(nextKey)
    return True
```

Comment: Sorry to say that, TweetListener Class is not returning anything to catch in the above definition mentioned  by you and also for multiple requests time.sleep(15*60) isn't a suitable solution, here my raises a new request with existing keys so that wasn't helpful. I couldn't get any response code from TweetListener class that was the main problem in that.

Comment: The on_limit solution appears not to work for me either. I used it and still get the 420 error and the on_limit function gets bypassed. (it doesnt print the string).

What exactly does that function do, and how is it called?

Answer (score 0):

Per the Twitter [error response code documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes)

> Returned when an application is being rate limited for making too many
>   requests.

The Twitter streaming API does not support more than a couple of connections per user and IP address. It is against the Twitter Developer Policy to use multiple application keys to attempt to circumvent this and your apps could be suspended if you do.

Comment: I agree with the constraints of twitter you mentioned, am developing a poc and in order to show app working is correct in terms of functionality, I used that method, for the full version of app gonna purchase keys from Twitter.